# Navigating file locations

Tags: python, file-io

I currently have a couple folders in a directory for my personal python project. The folders are modules and resources. I am writing a python file that will reside in the modules folder, but needs to access files from the resources folder.

The reason I have my project organized this way is I plan on having a bunch of separate .py files for the classes I will be making. Then in the root directory I will have my main script that will import from the classes when needed.

Side note: My project is a python script that will make rolling dice 1000 times more interesting by using the rolls and recording the information.

-Edit-

I'm not sure If I was clear but I need to know how some-file.py in the modules folder can read from some-other-file.txt in the resources folder. I can't hardcode the location as "C:/rootFolder/resources" as I plan to share this with friends(Plus I can't guarantee it will always remain in the same place on my own system).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the path to your directory which contains `modules` and `resources` folders to `system path`(sys.path) or `PYTHONPATH` and turn both `modules` and `resources` directories into [packages](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) by adding a `__init__.py` file.

Now to access those modules simply import them:

```
import modules
from modules import some_module
import modules.some_module
```

**Edit:**

To read a txt present in resources folder from a file in module folder use relative path:

```
with open("../resources/file.txt") as f:
    #do something with file
```

`..` means parent folder of current folder.

If your current working directory is not modules then use this:

```
import os
cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))      #path to current file
par_dir = os.path.split(cwd)[0]                        #path to parent directory
my_file =  os.path.join(par_dir,"resources/file.txt")  #path to file in resources dir
with open(myfile) as f:
    #do something
```

Comment: While this is useful information, I am unsure how this helps me. I have edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: That makes sense. I was not sure if that would work or not.

Comment: @RMDan It'll work if the current working directory is `modules` directory, in case if it's not then you've to use the absolute path method that I just added.

Answer (score 0):

A couple different different ways you can do this, using empty `__init__.py` files to indicate that it's a module directory ([from here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)):

```
sound/                          Top-level package
      __init__.py               Initialize the sound package
      modules/                  Subpackage for file format conversions
              __init__.py
              onefile.py
              auwrite.py
              ...
      resources/                  Subpackage for sound effects
              __init__.py
              another.py
              ...
      filters/                  Subpackage for filters
              __init__.py
              equalizer.py
              vocoder.py

              ...
```

Or you can add the directories to the PATH with `sys` ([more info here](http://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#modifying-python-s-search-path))

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/resources")
```

Comment: While this is useful information, I am unsure how this helps me. I have edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: `sys.path` is not `PYTHONPATH`, `sys.path` is a collections of multiple things and one of them is `PYTHONPATH`.